# populate json data in tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

javascript code

```
$(function(){
    $(".user").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var email = $(this).data("email");
        $.ajax({ 
            data:{email:email},                                                          
            type: "POST",                                                  
            url: 'getUser_detail.php',
            success: function(data) {        
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data['basic'].length; i++) {
                    $('#inputs').append('<label>Email:</label><input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="' + data['basic'][i].email + '" name="email[]" size="15">');
                    $('#inputs').append('<label>Password:</label><input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="'+ data['basic'][i].Pass +'" name="pass[]" size="5">');
                    $('#inputs').append('<label>Status:</label><input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="'+ data['basic'][i].status +'" name="pass[]" size="5">');
                    $('#inputs').append('<label>Acc. Address:</label><input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="'+ data['basic'][i].Accno +'" name="pass[]" size="44">');
                    $('#inputs').append('<label>Balance:</label><input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="'+ data['basic'][i].bal +'" name="pass[]" size="10">');
                }
                for( var j = 0; j<data['detail'].length; j++) {
                    var List = ["<tr><td>" + data['detail'][i].type + "</td><td>"+data['detail'][i].DB+"</td><td>"+data['detail'][i].LD+"</td><td>"+data['detail'][i].Prof+"</td><td>"+data['detail'][i].Server_stat+"</td></tr>"];
                }  
                $("#bodywallet").append(List);
            },
        });
    });
})
```

html code

```
<table class="table" id="wallet">
                    <thead class=" text-primary">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Type</th>
            <th class="text-left">Date_Bought</th>
            <th class="text-left">Expires</th>
            <th class="text-left">Profit</th>
            <th class="text-left">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-left" id="bodywallet" >
</tbody> 
  </table>
```

this is what my data should be display on table

[image]

but it is displaying the first record only

i have checked json is bringing all the required data. what i have done wrong what is the mistake.any help will be appreciated. thanks

php code

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($alEmailrslt))
{
 $json_array['detail'][] = $row2;
}

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Comment: SHow us ALL the javascript involved in the AJAX call please

Comment: @RiggsFolly plz have a look sir. i have edited my post

Comment: Also show us the PHP code that is reading the database and returning data to the AJAX call

Comment: added sir @RiggsFolly

Comment: It would be useful to know what is in the resultset, so show us a `var_dump($json_array)` as well please

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < data['detail'].length; j++) { wallet.push("<tr><td>" + data['detail'][j].type + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].DB + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].LD + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Prof + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Server_stat + "</td></tr>"); withdraw.push("<tr><td>" + data['detail'][j].addr + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Amt + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].WDStatus + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].WDdate + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].msg + "</td></tr>"); } is this the right approach? it is not displaying data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting everything in an array I and appending it every round.
You should use something like this instead:

```
success: function (data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    var list = []; // only one array
    for (var j = 0; j < data['detail'].length; j++) {
        // push to this array instead of overwriting the variable
        list.push("<tr><td>" + data['detail'][j].type + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].DB + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].LD + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Prof + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Server_stat + "</td></tr>");
    }
    // update html once
    // the join "glues" all parts of the array into one string
    $("#bodywallet").append(list.join());
}
```

Comment: Somehow you where using `i` as index but iterating over `j`. I corrected the code.

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < data['detail'].length; j++) {
        wallet.push("<tr><td>" + data['detail'][j].type + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].DB + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].LD + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Prof + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Server_stat + "</td></tr>");
        withdraw.push("<tr><td>" + data['detail'][j].addr + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].Amt + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].WDStatus + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].WDdate + "</td><td>" + data['detail'][j].msg + "</td></tr>");
  }   is this the right approach? it is not displaying data

Comment: Now you have the data in an array. Do something with it ;-) E.g. append it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think your list is not getting updated every time and the simplest approach would be, please find below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  this.json = {
    "Students": [{
        "id": "1",
        "hometown": "London",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "8",
        "name": "Lee",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "hometown": "NY",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "9",
        "name": "Shaldon",
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "hometown": "Paris",
        "gender": "Female",
        "GPA": "7",
        "name": "Julie",
      }
    ]
  };
  
  this.renderTable = function(Students) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Students.length; i++) {
      var tr = "<tr>";
      tr += "<td>ID</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].id + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>HomeTown</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].hometown + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>Gender</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].gender + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>GPA</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].GPA + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>NAME</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].name + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<hr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
    }
  }

  this.renderTable(this.json.Students);

  console.log(this.json.Students);
  //code for filtering//
  this.Filter = function() {
    var search = document.getElementById('search');
    var category = document.getElementById('category');
    var filteredObj = this.json.Students;
    filteredObj = $.map(this.json.Students, function(val, key) {
      if (search.value === val[category.value]) return val;
    });
    filteredObj.length>0 ? this.renderTable(filteredObj) : this.renderTable(this.json.Students);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<input id="search" type="search">
<select id = "category">
<option value = "select">select</option>
   <option value = "id">ID</option>
   <option value = "hometown">HomeTown</option>
   <option value = "gender">Gender</option>
   <option value = "GPA">GPA</option>
   <option value = "name">NAME</option>
  </select>
<button onclick="Filter()">Filter</button>

<table>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```